# Aggregate function over a given time interval spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please , i need your help please , i need to aggregate a dataset based on a 5 minute interval and aggregating based on average function ,here you may find input and expected output .,your help will be highly appreciated ,the first column is a timestamp column and am using scala language[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can extract the 5 minutes bucket from each time (e.g. by getting the timestamp as a number, dividing by 5 minutes and flooring the result).

Then you simply do:

```
df.groupBy("bucket").avg($"value")
```

Comment: Would you please update your code to  give how to get it done ,am just new to that  so i can accept your answer thank you a lot

Comment: Try doing the following: df.withColumn("bucket", ((unix_timestamp($"time") / 300).cast("long") * 300).cast("timestamp"))

Comment: Thanks a lot friend ,just one last question for the function avg , i would like to apply avg on all column existing in the dataset ,except the column time , how would it look ?